# Glue together two inline elements

Tags: html, css

I need to "glue together" two links, that are in the container.
The problem is that `.short` link can wrap to a new line separately from `.long`.
Ideally, I want that content of `.long` could be wrapped to a new line, and `.short` was "glued" to the last word of `.long`.

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
}

.long, .short {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="long">Here is some long text that can be wrapped to a new line</a>
    <a class="short">Short</a>
</div>
```

So, I can't apply `white-space: nowrap`, because `.long` can be wrapped to a new line.
And I can't place `.short` into the `.long` because it's two different links.

Any ideas how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you just display them `inline`, the links behave as normal text, so the long one will wrap to the next line (or even the one after that if it's reaaaally long) and the short one will be right after the last word of the long one. No need to display them `inline-block`

If you want to omit the whitespace; glue them together in your code as well. Like this;

```
<a href>long one</a><a href>short one, no space in between</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify width for .long and .sort class as per your requirement as below.

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
}

.long, .short {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a class="long">Here is some long text that can be wrapped to a new line</a>
    <a class="short">Short</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you've specified the anchors to be `inline-block`? If not - set them as `inline` or remove the `display` property completely. By default anchors will display inline as if it was a single continuous string:

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
}

.long, .short {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a class="long">Here is some long text that can be wrapped to a new line</a>
    <a class="short">Short</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the inline-block element creates a rectangular box around your text. pushing your .short class down...

You could try something like:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.long {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.short {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="long">Here is some long text that can be wrapped to a new line</a>
    <a href="#" class="short">Short</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps